# Use of ".//" in xpath

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, html-agility-pack

There are a lot of questions on SO about Xpath not working with HtmlAgilityPack. I read half a dozen of these, and did not find a solution to my problem.

I want to select all "input" elements that are inside a "form" element on any level.

I would expect this to work:

```
var all = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form//input");
```

It does not - no elements are returned. This does not work either (in this test case assuming a single form element, to narrow down the issue):

```
var node = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form");
var nodes = node.SelectNodes(".//input");
```

Now, all the above naturally works with xml:

```
XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
d.LoadXml("<html><body><form><div><input></input></div></form></body></html>");
var xmlNode = d.SelectSingleNode("//form");
var xmlNodes = xmlNode.SelectNodes(".//input");
Console.WriteLine($"Two step xml: {xmlNodes?.Count}");
var xmlAll = d.SelectNodes("//form//input");
Console.WriteLine($"One step xml: {xmlAll?.Count}");
```

The above displays count of 1 in both cases as expected.

Now the example for HtmlAgilityPack, which is NOT working:

```
string test = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=""en"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
<head id=""Head1"">    
  <body>
    <form method=""post"" action=""/SignIn"" id=""mainform"">
      <div class=""aspNetHidden"">
        <input type=""hidden"" name=""hello"" id=""hello"" value="""" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>";


HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(test);
var node = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form");
var nodes = node.SelectNodes(".//input");
Console.WriteLine($"Two steps html: {nodes?.Count}");
var all = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form//input");
Console.WriteLine($"One step html: {all?.Count}");
```

Here, 1 is not displayed, since no nodes are found.

**Why? Is it possible to fix the xpath expression without resorting to loops/code?**

I'm designing a class that needs to accept a single xpath expression (that might come for configuration and/or data store) to know what subset of nodes it needs to work on.

Comment: There are indeed a lot of questions regarding HtmlAgilityPack and xpath, mostly because its xpath implementation is incorrect and not up with generic xpath specifications.

Comment: I prefer using Lamda. Something like doc.Descendents("form") and for each returned node look for Descendents("input")

Comment: @HungCao lambda is not an option. You cannot store that in a database or in a config file. xpath you can.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: @Granitosaurus, would you like to make an answer from your comment? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Granitosaurus comment:

> There are indeed a lot of questions regarding HtmlAgilityPack and xpath, mostly because its xpath implementation is incorrect and not up with generic xpath specifications.

Answer (score 0):

So there's nothing wrong with your code. The problem is HTMLAgilityPack itself.
Basically you need to add this line 
`HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");`